# MySQL- INDEX(): How to Create a Functional Key Part Using Last nth Characters?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

How would I write the INDEX() statement to use the last Nth characters of a functional keypart?  I'm brand new to SQL/MySQL, and believe that's the proper verbiage of my question.  explanation of what I'm looking for is below.

The MySQL 8.0 Ref Manual explains how to use the first nth characters, showing that the secondary index using col2's first 10 characters, [via example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  col1 VARCHAR(40),
  col2 VARCHAR(30),
  INDEX (col1, col2(10))
);
```

However, I would like to know how one could form this using the ending characters?  Perhaps something like:

```
...
 INDEX ((RIGHT (col2,3)));
);
```

However, I think that says to index over a column called 'xyz' instead of "put an index on each column value using the last 3 of 30 potential characters"?  That's what I'm really trying to figure out.

For some context, it'd be helpful to index something with smooshed/mixed data and am playing around as to how such a thing could be accomplished.  Example of the kind of data I'm talking about, below, is a simplified, adjusted version of exported data from an inventory/billing manager that hails from the 90's that I had to endure some years back...:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| GP6500012_SALES_FY2023_SBucks_503_Thurs | R-DK_Sumat__SKU-503-20230174 |
| GP6500012_SALES_FY2023_SBucks_607_Mon | R-MD_Columb__SKU-607-2023035 |
| GP6500012_SALES_FY2023_SBucks_627_Mon-pm | R-BLD_House__SKU-503-20230024 |
| GP6500012_SALES_FY2023_SBucks_929_Wed | R-FR_Ethp__SKU-929-20230324 |

Undoubtedly, better options exist that bypass this question altogether- and I'll presumably learn those techniques with time in my data analytics coursework.  For now, I'm just curious if it's possible to somehow index the rows by suffix instead of prefix, and what a code example would look like to accomplish that.  TIA.

Comment: Thinking more, `INDEX ((RIGHT (col2,3)));` would still be a prefix?  I'll play with it later.  
  

Documentation says the prefix cannot be an expression, but cites CAST () and SUBSTRING() to do workarounds.  I haven't yet found explanation on how to do such a workaround; CAST() has no explanation beyond showing syntax. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).  


Maybe col1 would have been a better example to prevent confusion as only strings can be functional key parts...  Apologies if this did confuse anyone!  I appreciate the patience, pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Proposed solution (`INDEX ((RIGHT (col2,3)))`):

Not available.

Case 1:

When you need to split apart a column to search it, you have probably designed the schema wrong.  In particular, that part of the columns needs to be in its own column.  That being said, it is possible to use a 'virtual' (or 'generated') column that is a function of the original column, then `INDEX` that.

Case 2:

If you are suggesting that the last 3 characters are the most selective and that might speed up any lookup, don't bother.  Simply index the entire column.

That data:

I would consider splitting up the stuff that is concatenated together by `_`.  Do it as you `INSERT` the rows.  If it needs to be put back together, do so during subsequent `SELECTs`.

DATEs:

Do not, on the other hand, split up dates (into year, month, etc).  Keep them together.  (That's another discussion.)  Always go to the effort to convert dates (and datetimes) to the MySQL format (year-first) when storing.  That way, you can properly use indexes and use the many date functions.

MySQL's Prefix indexing:

In general it is a "bad idea" to use the `INDEX(col(10))` construct.  It rarely is of any benefit; it often fails to use the index as much as you would expect.  This is especially deceptive:  `UNIQUE(col(10))` -- It declares that the first 10 chars are unique, not the entire `col`!

CAST:

If the data is the wrong datatype (string vs int; wrong collation; etc), the I argue that it is a bad schema design.  This is a common problem with EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) schemas.  When a number is stored as a string, `CAST` is needed to sort (`ORDER BY`) it.

Functional indexes:

Your proposed solution not a "prefix", it is something more complicated.  I suspect any expression, even on non-string columns will work.  This is when it became available:

> ---- 2018-10-22 8.0.13 General Availability -- -- -----
>
> MySQL now supports creation of functional index key parts that index
> expression values rather than column values. Functional key parts
> enable indexing of values that cannot be indexed otherwise, such as
> JSON values. For details, see CREATE INDEX Syntax.

Comment: Rick,

Thank you for the time you spent in answering and bring up additional points.  Seeing some of your thought process here is valuable to my learning efforts.

A small part of me was thinking that trying to force a solution would encounter diminishing returns very quickly.  I can't recall where I saw it (...LaTeX website?) but a phrase with the gist of 'brain power > time' comes to mind.

More importantly, I'll spend additional time going through each of your points, including schema design, functional indexing, etc.  Thanks again!